# GROUP BY with CASE expression IN PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, case

This is my query:

```
SELECT userid,
  case when extract(day from date )=1 then  string_agg(status,'') end "1" ,
  case when extract(day from date )=2 then  string_agg(status,'') end "2" ,
.
.
.
  case when extract(day from date )=31 then string_agg(status,'') end "31"
from attendance.attendance group by userid;
```

But I have the next error:

```
ERROR:  column "attendance.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

When group by `userid` and `date` the output:

```
userid 1 2 3 ... 31
1      P
1        A
1          P ... 
1                P
```

I want to group by `userid` like this:

```
userid 1 2 3 ... 31
1      P A P ... P
2      P P P ... P
etc.
```

Any ideas? I'll very appreciate.

Comment: Postgres 9.2, really? Please update to a still maintained version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put the `string_agg` *around* the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT userid,
  string_agg(case when extract(day from date)=1 then status end) "1" ,
  string_agg(case when extract(day from date)=2 then status end) "2" ,
  .
  .
  .
  string_agg(case when extract(day from date)=31 then status end) "31"
FROM attendance.attendance
GROUP BY userid;
```

A nicer way to write this query would be using a `FILTER` for the aggregate:

```
SELECT userid,
  string_agg(status) FILTER (WHERE extract(day from date)=1) "1" ,
  string_agg(status) FILTER (WHERE extract(day from date)=2) "2" ,
  .
  .
  .
  string_agg(status) FILTER (WHERE extract(day from date)=31) "31"
FROM attendance.attendance
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: thanks for answering. But I'm getting error with both Querys ERROR:  function string_agg(character) does not exist:
`
LINE 2:   string_agg(case when extract(day from date)=1 then status...
          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
`

Comment: Sounds like you need to cast your `status` character to a string then: `string_agg(status::text)`. I'm surprised this worked in your original code

Comment: Thank you so much @Bergi. The function is string_agg(SOMEVALUE, '').  I have changed my query to: ``` string_agg(case when extract(day from date)=31 then status end,'') "31" ```